Installing Managed Module in IIS for use with ColdFusion Application
Windows 2022, IIS 10, DLL written/compiled under .NET 4.8, ColdFusion 2021
I have this DLL that I've compiled for use in IIS. It's very simple - it is supposed to create a header with a dynamic value for each request, and also send the same header back in the response to the client.  I would like to know the very simplest way to install this DLL as a module in IIS, without having to go through the extra steps to use the Global Application Cache (GAC).
I have a ColdFusion application that is running under a site in IIS.
I created a \bin directory in my ColdFusion app, and put my DLL file there.
It should be noted that for my local install, IIS is configured to use a directory on drive Y: as the webroot, and that's where the bin directory is with my file in it.  In production, the webroot will be a local (D:) drive on that system. I don't think this matters, but is worth mentioning in case it does.
So... how can I get my DLL recognized by IIS with the least amount of hassle?

Which guide did you follow to create this module? And what's the base class of your module? You have to edit the question to make such clear so others might suggest you look for. The official guide is in https://learn.microsoft.com/iis/develop/runtime-extensibility/developing-a-module-using-net#task-2-deploy-the-module-to-the-application but it's not an easy task to follow all the steps.

First make sure the DLL is in the correct directory, then register the DLL as an IIS module (if necessary), and finally make sure .NET Framework 4.8 is installed and configured，restart IIS test your ColdFusion application.

I do not know what the "correct directory" is.  Windows has .NET4.8 installed. Without using GAC, it seems the most common place to put the dll is in the web app's \bin directory. I have tried registering it as as Managed Module and have restarted IIS, but it seems IIS cannot find the file.

I figured it out... Complete noob... turns out my code needed to be in a namespace.
Thanks for all who answered, you guided me in the right direction.
